# Не работает пошаговая отладка GDB в Debian QT

Tags: linux, qt, debian, qtcreator

Имею:

1. Виртуальную систему Debian 10 x64
2. Qt Creator 4.8.2 и Qt 5.11.3

Не работает пошаговая отладка. Всегда включается уровень дизассемблирования.
При сборке выставлено "отладка".
Уровень инструкций отключен.

Ниже приведён скриншот с процессом отладки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться привычной пошаговой отладки? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была подобная проблема. Решилась с помощью перемещения директории. У вас есть не латинские буквы в пути?

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, дело действительно было в русских символах.